# how can I attach authentication headers to all requests generated from a page on phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I'm using phantom js for printing pdfs and pngs of a website. I'm using angular4 for the fronted and node with express for backend.

I want to attach authentication headers to all requests generated from phantomjs on that specific page, I used the following code:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = {
  width: 1700,
  height: 1225
};

//page.clipRect = { top: 80, left: 0, width: 3400, height: 2290 };
//page.zoomFactor = 2;

page.customHeaders = {
  "Authorization": "JWT "
  token - goes - here ""
};
```

The problem is that this only attaches headers to the initial request for the page. Can I write javascript to attach this header to all requests originating from that page? Suppose that specific page has to call an API and I want my auth token to be attached to that request!

Comment: Okay, I'll do that!

Comment: I can't seem to find the option for editing my question (I'm quite new on stack overflow). should I delete the question altogether?